# Preventing Spark from storing state in stream/stream joins

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I have two streaming datasets, let's call them `fastStream` and `slowStream`.

The `fastStream` is a streaming dataset that I am consuming from Kafka via the structured streaming API. I am expecting to receive potentially thousands of messages a second.

The `slowStream` is actually a reference (or lookup) table that is being 'upserted' by another stream and contains data that I want to join on to each message in the `fastStream` before I save the records to a table. The `slowStream` is only updated when someone changes the metadata, which can happen at any time but we would expect to change maybe once every few days.

Each record in the `fastStream` will have exactly one corresponding message in the `slowStream` and I essentially want to make that join happen immediately with whatever data is in the `slowStream` table. I don't want to wait to see if a potential match could occur if new data arrives in the `slowStream`.

The problem that I have is that according to the Spark docs:

> Hence, for both the input streams, we buffer past input as streaming state, so that we can match every future input with past input and accordingly generate joined results.

I have tried adding a watermark to the `fastStream` but I think it has no effect since the docs indicate that the watermarked columns need to be referenced in the join

Ideally I would write something like:

```py
# Apply a watermark to the fast stream
fastStream = spark.readStream \
.format("delta") \
.load("dbfs:/mnt/some_file/fastStream") \
.withWatermark("timestamp", "1 hour") \
.alias("fastStream")

# The slowStream cannot be watermarked since it is only slowly changing
slowStream = spark.readStream \
.format("delta") \
.load("dbfs:/mnt/some_file/slowStream") \
.alias("slowStream")

# Prevent the join from buffering the fast stream by 'telling' spark that there will never be new matches.
fastStream.join( 
  slowStrean,
  expr(""" 
    fastStream.slow_id = slowStream.id
    AND fastStream.timestamp > watermark
    """
  ),
  "inner"
).select("fastStream.*", "slowStream.metadata")
```

But I don't think you can reference the `watermark` in the SQL expression.

Essentially, while I'm happy to have the `slowStream` buffered (so the whole table is in memory) I can't have the `fastStream` buffered as this table will quickly consume all memory. Instead, I would simply like to drop messages from the `fastStream` that aren't matched instead of retaining them to see if they might match in future.

Any help very gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question with what I ended up going with. It's certainly not ideal but for all my searching, there doesn't seem to be the control within Spark structured streaming to address this use case.

So my solution was to read the dataset and conduct the join inside a `foreachBatch`. This way I prevent Spark from storing a ton of unnecessary state and get the joins conducted immediately. On the downside, there seems to be no way to incrementally read a stream table so instead, I am re-reading the entire table every time...

```py
def join_slow_stream(df, batchID):
    
  # Read as a table rather than a stream
  slowdf = spark.read \
    .format("delta") \
    .load("dbfs:/mnt/some_file/slowStream") \
    .alias("slowStream")
  
  out_df = df.join(
    slowdf,
    expr(""" 
      fastStream.slow_id = slowStream.id
      """
    ),
    "inner"
  ).select("fastStream.*", "slowStream.metadata")

  # write data to database
  db_con.write(out_df)



fastStream.writeStream.foreachBatch(join_slow_stream)
```

Answer (score 6):

For *inner* Stream-Stream joins watermarking and event-time constraints (join condition) are optional.

If an unbounded state is not an issue for you in terms of volume you can choose not to specify them. In that case, all data will be buffered and your data from the fastStream will immediately be joined with all the data from the slowStream.

Only when both parameters are specified your state will be cleaned up. Note the purpose of those two parameters:

- **Event-time constraint (time range join condition):** What ist the maximum time range between the *generation* of the two events at their respective sources?
- **Watermark:** What is the maximum duration an event can be *delayed in transit* between the source and the processing engine?

To define the two parameters you need to first answer the above mentioned questions (which are quoted from the book "Learning Apache Spark, 2nd edition" published by O`Reilly).

Regarding your code comment:

> "Prevent the join from buffering the fast stream by 'telling' spark that there will never be new matches."

Remember that buffering in stream-stream join is necessary. Otherwise you would just be able to join the data that is available within the current micro-batch. As the slowStream does not have regular updates but the fastStream is updating its data quite fast you would probably never get any join matches at all without buffering the data.

Overall, for the use case you are describing ("Join fast changing data with slow changing metadata") it is usually better to use a **stream-static** join approach where the slow changing data becomes the static part.

In a stream-static join every row in the stream data will be joined with the full static data whereas the static table is loaded in every single micro-batch. If loading the static table reduces your performance you may think about caching it and have it updated regularly as described in [Stream-Static Join: How to refresh (unpersist/persist) static Dataframe periodically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66154867/stream-static-join-how-to-refresh-unpersist-persist-static-dataframe-periodic).

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in referencing the "time that was watermarked" i.e. the 1 hour, you may replace `watermark` in the expression with `current_timestamp - interval '1' hour`.

Since you are attempting to join two streams, spark will insist that both use watermarks

### Reference

- [Spark Stream to Stream Joins](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.2/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#stream-stream-joins)