# Spark structured streaming - Stream - Static Join: How to update static DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

My question is almost the same as this one: [Stream-Static Join: How to refresh (unpersist/persist) static Dataframe periodically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66154867/stream-static-join-how-to-refresh-unpersist-persist-static-dataframe-periodic)

However solution from @Michael Heil didn't for my code.

Another similar question is: [How can I update a broadcast variable in spark streaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33372264/how-can-i-update-a-broadcast-variable-in-spark-streaming)

In this question @Aastha proposed another solution, which is also not work.

I am building an PySpark structured streaming data analysis application. What I need to do is load stream data (`stream_df`) from kafka and filter it by joining another DataFrame, say `static_df`.  And the `static_df` is updated periodically.

At the very first, I think I could simply update the `static_df` since it's looks like a common case. However, after I tried every solutions, I found that any update for `static_df` will not appear to have no impact on my streaming process (Of course the `static_df` is a global variable).

Below is my code (I use  to replace some unimportant vars)

1. Pulling & parse data from a kafka topic

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .getOrCreate()

stream_df = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "<kafka_servers>") \
    .option("subscribe", "<kafka_topic>") \
    .load()

# decode & parse data
# where `domain` contains valid or invalid domains
# and we need to get valid domains with inner join function
stream_df = stream_df \
    # ...decode & parse kafka messages \
    .select("domain", "msg")
```

2. Create `static_df` from API calling

```
df_api_url = spark \
    .createDataFrame(
        ["<api_url>",], ["url",]
    ) \
    .cache()

# A udf return `StructType()` results
udf = F.udf(lambda url: requests.get(url).json(), <schema>)

def get_static_df():
    # column `domain` is a array contains lots of valid domains
    ret = df_api_url \
        .select(udf("url").alias("result") \
        .select("result.domain")
    return ret

static_df = get_static_df().cache()
```

3. Filtering `stream_df` by joining with `static_df` and do some analysis

```
stream_df = stream_df \
    .join(F.broadcast(static_df), "domain", "inner")

# do some analysis here

# output results to console for debugging
query1 = stream_df \
    .writeStream \
    .format("console") \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .option("truncate", "false") \
    .start()
```

Everything goes fine until now. Now we need to update static_df periodically since the valid domains is changing from time to time.

4. Update `static_df` every hour

```
def update_static_df(batch_df, batch_id):
    if batch_id == 0:
        return
    static_df.unpersist()
    static_df = get_static_df().cache()
   
# Here we use a rate stream to periodically run the func `update_static_df`
query2 = spark \
    .readStream \
    .option("rate") \
    .option("rowsPerSecond", 1) \
    .option("numPartitions", num_partitions) \
    .load()
    .writeStream \
    .trigger(processingTime="3600 seconds") \
    .foreachBatch(update_static_df) \
    .start()
```

Code in step 4 is just on of my attempts, I also tried construct a BroadcastWarpper and update broadcast variable periodically by setting a TTL time.

When the valid domain changes, output from query1 keeps unchange and output those domains in `static_df` before it updates.

I guess, once a structured streaming query starts, a DAG will be created and each static variables (include cached DataFrame) will "frozen" by Spark. And any change make to those static variables will have on impact on the structured streaming process.

The only solution I found is to run join function in `foreachBatch`:

```
def join_and_print(batch_df, batch_id):
    batch_df = batch_df \
        .join(F.broadcast(static_df), "domain", "inner")
    print(str(batch_df.collect()))

# stream_df from step 1
query3 = stream_df \
    .writeStream \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .foreachBatch(join_and_print) \
    .start()
```

But this solution is not suitable for every situations, such as a groupby with time window after join.

So, is there any advise for my problem?